# How can I copy part of a column (text) to another column in other sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to duplicate part of the content of a column (text) to another column in other sheet. For example, I have column A in Sheet1 and I want to show only a word of this column in Sheet2. [Here an example file](https://docs.google.com/a/uauline.com.br/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AniNhuMSLF0_dHJEWmVzVTlDS0NyYVlTMjZ6MzNNcmc#gid=5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how to do that with a script.

### Code

```
function myFind(findRange) {
  var output = [];
  var find = ["Vault", "Drive", "Apps"];

  for(var i=0, iLen=findRange.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    for(var j=0, jLen=find.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      if(findRange[i][0].indexOf(find[j]) !== -1) {
        output.push([find[j]]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

### Explained

The range is searched by the key words in the *find* array. Once a word is found, the search is stopped and the next search will commence. You can add more key words in the *var find*  array.

### Note

The order of key words is very important. Better is to choose unique key words, like:

- Google Vault
- Google Drive
- Google Apps

All is of course dependent upon the data available.

### Example

I've added the script (Tools>Script editor) and the `ARRAYFORMULA` version of the solution Punchlinern provided in your example file.

Comment: Perfect! I adopted the script solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have those three strings to search for (`Apps`, `Drive` and `Vault`), you could use the following function, as [suggested by shipr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11869051/739534) (edited to suit your cause and Google Spreadsheets):

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Vault";DATA!A2);0);"Vault";IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Drive";DATA!A2);0);"Drive";IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Apps";DATA!A2);0);"Apps";"None")))
```

Paste it into the first cell in the `TABLE` sheet and copy down. 
It's not overly beautiful, you have to add the `IFERROR`-part for every word you want to search for, but it works.

Comment: Perhaps you can turn it into an `ARRAYFORMULA`?

Comment: I've just recently started discovering those, so I'm not natively using them yet. What is the benefit of using an `ARRAYFORMULA` in this case?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14195594#14195594